# SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier in IE11 Laravel Vuejs Vestjs

Tags: php, laravel, webpack, vuejs2, laravel-mix

I normally use [laravel-mix](https://laravel-mix.com/) with [laravel-mix-polyfill](https://laravel-mix.com/extensions/polyfill) in a Laravel-Vuejs project with no problems on IE11.

Without testing on IE11, I continued my development by using only Chrome for testing. I did use a new plugin to me, the [Vestjs](http://vestjs.dev/) plugin that I've used for validations. I am really not sure if that was the cause of my problem.

This was the console error shown on my IE:

```
SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier
dashboard.js (7602,11)
```

Attached image is the `dashboard.js (7602,11)`:
[image]

`webpack.mix.js`

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
require('laravel-mix-polyfill');

mix.js('resources/js/dashboard.js', 'public/js').vue()
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css')
    .postCss('resources/css/lineshop.css', 'public/css')
    .postCss('resources/css/ec-date-picker.css', 'public/css')
    .polyfill({
        enabled: true,
        useBuiltIns: 'usage',
        targets: 'firefox 50, IE 11',
    })
    .sourceMaps(false)
    .version();
```

I am not that familiar with setting up babel. Is there anything I can do to fix this with [laravel-mix](https://laravel-mix.com/) and [laravel-mix-polyfill](https://laravel-mix.com/extensions/polyfill) setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading the version of `vestjs` to ^4.0.0 fixed the issue. But you might encounter issues with the functionalities in IE 11.

For the workaround, I created a temporary validation library that was like the `vestjs` while waiting for the fix of the plugin.